# rails nested attributes validations with has_one relation condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have an Order model which has_one required delivery_address and an optional billing_address. Order has an bool attribute has_billing_address. In my form i'm accepting nested attributes:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :delivery_address, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :billing_address, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :delivery_address, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address, allow_destroy: true

end
```

There are validations on both address models for field presence. I only want to create the billing_address if @order.has_billing_address? is true and the validations on billing_address should also just trigger when there is a billing address.

My order controller looks like this:

```
def address
  if session['order_id'].blank?
    @order = Order.new
    @order.delivery_address = DeliveryAddress.new
    @order.billing_address = BillingAddress.new
  else
    @order = Order.find(session['order_id'])
    ##### PROBLEM fails cause of validation:
    @order.billing_address = BillingAddress.new if @order.billing_address.blank?
  end
end

def process_address
  has_billing_address = params[:order][:has_billing_address].to_i
  params[:order].delete(:billing_address_attributes) if has_billing_address.zero?
  if session['order_id'].blank?
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    @order.billing_address = nil if has_billing_address.zero?
    @order.cart = session_cart
    if @order.save
      session['order_id'] = @order.id
      redirect_to payment_order_path
    else
      render "address"
    end
  else
    @order = Order.find(session['order_id'])
    @order.billing_address = nil if has_billing_address.zero?
    if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
      redirect_to payment_order_path
    else
      render "address"
    end
  end
end
```

I'm really stuck on this - there should be no validation on billing_address if @order.has_billing_address? is false - i can't use an if proc on the validation of the BillingAddress model cause there are times where there is no order associated to the model. And there is another problem when returning to action address if order already exists and no billing address is set i have to show the nested billing address form again so i call @order.billing_address = BillingAddress.new then it tells me that it cant be saved cause the validations fail for it.

Any ideas? It's a little bit confusing with nested attributes. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this validation in your billing address model:

```
validate :field_name, :presence => true, :if => 'order.has_billing_address?'
```

Edit (Try with Proc) :

```
validate :field_name, :presence => true, if: Proc.new { |c| c.order.has_billing_address?}
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. if the validation is like this the validation doesn't get triggered at all.

Comment: ok the validation gets triggered but when no order exists which can be the case i: get undefined method `has_billing_address?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: if you have nested attributes, order should always be there. Other wise, you can pass multiple condition like:
validate :field_name, :presence => true, if: Proc.new { |c| c.order.present? && c.order.has_billing_address?}

Comment: ok i changed the way the order works. so order is always present now. if i use the proc condition the validation doesnt get triggered until has_billing_address is saved which means it gets triggered if i updated a record two times. is there any workaround? proc.new reads the current value of order in db..

Comment: aah i just update the order with has_billing_address before i call update_attributes then the validation of the billing_address works. Thanks!