# Rails 4 - has_one - Can't access attributes of related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to develop a small Rails 4 app but I'm having some troubles - there's a lot of differente things from older Rails versions.

When I try to get the attributes of a related model, I receive a `PG::UndefinedColumn:` error. The related model was associated by `has_one` relationship, but I will explain my models better bellow.

---

### Now I have the following architecture:

**Site (officialy, this is called "item"):**

- id
- name
- description
- url
- country_id (Country FK)
- category_id (Category FK)

**Category:**

- id
- name

**Country:**

- id
- name

### Site Model:

```
has_one :country
accepts_nested_attributes_for :country

has_one :category 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :category
```

### Country and Category Model (both are equals):

```
has_many :site
```

### Migrations:

```
    # timestamp_add_column_idcountry_to_site
    # Adding reference (Foreign Key) of country to Site (Now Site will have a country_id field).
    add_reference :sites, :country, index: true

    # timestamp_add_column_idcategory_to_site
    # Adding reference (Foreign Key) of category to Site (Now Site will have a category_id field).
    add_reference :sites, :category, index: true
```

### My view:

```
<%= @category.site.each do |store| %>
    <h1>Name: <%= store.name %></h1>
    <h3>Country: <%= store.country.name %> </h3>
<% end %>
```

### The error:

(in store.**country.name** )

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column countries.site_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries"  WHERE "countries"."i...
                                                      ^
: SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries"  WHERE "countries"."site_id" = $1  ORDER BY "countries"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Do you need some other information? If yes, please tell me and I will try to edit the question faster. **What can I do to access the "site.country.name" attribute?**

P.S: I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510813/rails-nested-attributes-validations-with-has-one-relation-condition) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225002/accessing-a-has-one-associations-attributes) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by janfoeh, you should have the following code in your Site model:

```
belongs_to :country
belongs_to :category
```

That way, you can do `Site.find(1).country` to return a site's country or `Country.find(1).sites` to return all sites found in a certain country.

If you want to do the "has_one" route, your data model should look like:

Site:

- id
- name
- description
- url

Category:

- id
- name
- site_id

Country:

- id
- name
- site_id

You should also change the code for your Country and Category models to have:

```
belongs_to :site
```

Comment: This works @Gjaldon, thanks! Just one more thing, for me make no sense a Site "belongs to" Country. Site "has one" Country, not belongs to. There's any other way to do that without f*** the semantic?

Comment: I think it also makes sense that a Site belongs to a Country so you could do `Country.find(name: "UK").sites` to list all sites that are found in a certain country. If you prefer using a has_one association, I updated my answer with that method.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Site#has_one :country` needs to be `Site#belongs_to :country`.